# Trying to use os.walk to and FreqDist for all files in a directory and subdirectories

Tags: python, nltk, attributeerror, os.walk, word-frequency

I'm trying to use NLTK to get the most common words used in an entire directory consisting of around a dozen sub-directories with around a dozen to two-dozen text files in each. I'm using the os.walk function and NLTK's FreqDist, but my code doesn't seem to work. I've tried lots but can't get it to run. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to include the sub-directories in the line:

```
with open(os.path.join(directory, subdirectory, file), "r") as f:
```

The error is because `subdirectory` is a list.

You only need:

```
 with open(os.path.join(directory, file), "r") as f:
```

---

To report the total for all the files, you can create one

```
frequency = nltk.FreqDist()
```

before the loop and then update it within the loop

```
frequency.update(useful_words)
```

and then report

```
print(frequency.most_common(20))
```

after the loop.

`nltk.FreqDist` is a subclass of `collections.Counter`.

Comment: Hey,

I tried this and it only gave me the frequency for the first file in the first subdirectory. Not sure why.

Comment: You also need to indent the rest of the code so that it is at the same indent level as the data = f.read() line.

Comment: Thanks, Dan!

While that did work, it gave me the 20 most frequent for every file separately. Is there a way to make it print the 20 most common and their frequency in total (if that makes sense)?

Comment: You can create one `frequency = nltk.FreqDist()` before the loop and then update it within the loop `frequency.update(useful_words)` and then report `print(frequency.most_common(20))` after the loop.  `nltk.FreqDist` is a subclass of `collections.Counter`.

Comment: Dan, you are a saint. Works perfectly now. I get a unicode error, but since I'm working with an email dataset, I kinda expected that. Does it affect my output?

Comment: You could catch the error and report the file and look at the file to see why it didn't decode. The files contents would not be included in the frequencies.

Comment: Huh, interesting. The unicode warning seems to be to do with the useful_words section. When removed, I don't get the warning (but also get a ton of junk).